# Using a file input as stdin for a shell script does not work

Tags: linux, shell, input, stdin

I have the following script code:

**test.sh**

```
echo "BEGIN"
while read CMD <&1; do
    [ -z "$CMD" ] && continue
    case "$CMD" in
    start)
            echo "get_start"
            ;;
    stop)
            echo "get_stop"
            ;;
    *)
            echo "get_uknown_command"
            ;;
    esac
    echo "END";
done
```

When I run it with:

```
$./test.sh <input.txt
```

I get my script locked

**input.txt**

```
start
stop
sthh
```

Why my script is locked? How I can fix that?

BTW: If I enter the data manually then the script will not lock.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're using the wrong file descriptor.  `1` is stdout, `0` is stdin.

Change:

```
while read CMD <&1; do
```

to:

```
while read CMD <&0; do
```

And it will from the file correctly.  However, you don't need to do that all since `read` defaults to using stdin:

```
while read CMD; do
```

Also, the `-u` option can be used to read from a particular file descriptor (at least in bash).  So you could do this as well:

```
while read -u 0 CMD; do
```

Answer (score 2):

File descriptor `1` is `stdout` or *standard output*. Which means that you are *redirecting `read`'s input to come from standard output*. This clearly isn't going to work very well; there will almost certainly never be any input waiting on the standard output for `read`.

Standard input is file descriptor `0`, so if you change `<&1` to `<&0` on line 2 of your script, it works. Or simply drop that part entirely; `read` reads from standard input by default (that's pretty much its purpose), so there's no need to explicitly tell it to read from standard input.

If you want to read some particular input interactively and allow the remainder to be redirected from a file (or come through a pipe), you can do `read </dev/tty`.

And you don't need the semicolon statement separator after the END echo; the newline does just fine.